# Can I identify an java applet event locally with bash or python?

Tags: java, applet

Is there any way to simplify watching a java chat applet on a website, and when a specific event occurs within that chat applet, do something.

If a user 'tips' the java applet on their side will send a line to the chatroom globally for all to see, showing the amount, it also plays a sound based on the tip amount, approximately 4 different sounds cover the range of 1 - 1000, I want to take this line, or the event that triggers these sounds to play locally in my browser, and depending on its numerical content (the tip amount), or the sound event, send a byte over serial output to /dev/ttyACM0.

I am trying to explain my requirements but I keep being told I am explaining 'too much', I did explain what tips were, apparently out of context, so here I have limited it down as much as possible which will probably get me flamed for not being specific enough, good ole internetz..

If you can help me find a starting point, that would be great.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Not in any easy way. You would probably need to integrate into NSAPI, otherwise you'd be looking at some form of screen capturing solution.

Considering that Applets are dying out (I think none of the newest browsers support them), you'd be better off spending your time on something more useful.